# Dealing with a user dependent application

Tags: domain-driven-design

An application that I'm currently writing is heavily dependent on the current logged in user, to give a concrete example lets say we have a list of Products.

Now every user has the 'rights' to see certain Products, particular details of this product, and edit / remove fewer of those.

E.g.:

- The user can see 3/5 products
- The user can see extra details from 2 out of those 3 products
- ...

As this is the case with most of the application's domain, I have a tendency to pass around the user in most methods. Which becomes cumbersome from time to time. As I have to pass in the user in some methods, just to pass it down to another one that needs it.

My gut tells me I'm missing something, but I'm not sure how I could tackle this problem.

I gave some thoughts at using a Class that holds this user, and inject that class everywhere I need it. Or using a static Property.

Now from time to time it is handy pass in the user in the method, I guess I could override it then:

```
public doSomething(User user = null)
{
    var u = user ?? this.authService.User;
    ...
}
```

Are there other ways you could tackle this kind of problem ?

Comment: I would keep passing the user. If the user object is needed than it should be passed. I can't see anything wrong about this approach and my gut is telling me it is an ok solution. Using a static property to get the user can make the code hard to test since it is easier to mock the user and pass it as parameter in the tests.

Comment: It was what I was thinking initially. But I'm repeating this so often that I'm looking at possible alternatives

Comment: It might seem not very pretty having the user object everywhere. Maybe sometimes it shouldn't be passed. Some functions will only need the user role or preferences. I can't tell since there is not enough details but think about passing to the function only the data it needs. I think this can be a small possible improvement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gut is correct, keep listen to it.

Authorization checks should not be mixed with core domain checks. For example, the `if` that checks that the user may update the product details and the `if` that checks that the product details are long enough should not be contained in the same class or even the same bounded context. If you have a monolith then the two checks should be contained in separate namespaces/modules.

Now I will tell you how I do it. In my latest monolithic project I use CQRS a lot, I like the separation between Commands and Queries. I will give an example of command validation but this can be extended to query validation and even to non-CQRS architectures.

For every command I register zero or more command validators that check if the command may be sent to the `aggregate`. These validators are eventual consistent. If a command passes all the validators then the command is sent to the `aggregate` where it is further checked but in a strong consistent manner. So, we are talking about two kinds of validation: validation outside the aggregate and validation inside the aggregate. The checks that belongs to other bounded context can be implemented using command validators outside the aggregate, that's how I do it. And now some example source code, in PHP:

```
<?php
namespace CoreDomain {
    class ProductAggregate
    {
        public function handle(ChangeProductDetails $command):void //no return value
        {
            //this check is strong consistent
            //the method yields zero or more events or exception in case of failure
            if (strlen($command->getProductDetails()) < 10) {
                throw new \Exception("Product details must be at least 10 characters long");
            }

            yield new ProductDetailsWereChanged($command->getProductId(), $command->getProductDetails());
        }
    }
}

namespace Authorization {
    class UserCanChangeProductDetailsValidator
    {
        private $authenticationReaderService;
        private $productsPermissionsService;

        public function validate(ChangeProductDetails $command): void //no return value, if all is good no exception are thrown
        {
            //this check is eventual consistent
            if (!$this->productsPermissionsService->canUserChangeProductDetails($this->authenticationReaderService->getAuthenticatedUserId(), $command->getProductId())) {
                throw new \Exception("User may not change product details");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This example uses a style where commands are sent directly to the aggregates but you should apply this pattern to other styles too. For brevity, the details of command validators registering are not included.

Comment: This is interesting ! Would the query for getting the product list for a particular user be encapsulated in an aggregate as well, where the command holds the user (if the (sql)-query requires the user_id to fire)

Comment: @RVandersteen The queries should not be the aggregate's concern. Maybe the Repository has this responsibility as it is best at finding products (but only by ID) or in a domain service that has the SQL connection injected. In CQRS, because of the separation, the things are simpler, you just create a read-model that is super-optimized for finding all the user's products.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to depend on where you are in the project in terms of progress.  In some instances you may not have the leeway to change this but if you have more control or are starting out then you may have options.

Typically *Identity & Access Control* is a bounded context on its own.  Authentication and authorization should not be in your core domain.  Your core domain (or even sub-domains) are interested in doing what they do **if you have access** but it is not the domain's responsibility to determine that access.

The authorization should take place outside the domain.  If you find that you are querying your domain then things probably need to change since you need a dedicated query layer that will probably apply the authorization.  Any commands that are limited will have authorization applied at the integration/application layer.  Whether we want to restrict a user from registering a new order or even new orders of a certain type should not really matter i.t.o. the domain since it is only the granularity that changes.

You may have a sub-domain that deals with the authorization specific to your domain and an *Identity & Access Control* generic sub-domain that is more orthogonal.

But you may be in a scenario where there is an uncomfortably high level of coupling between the data element authorization (a level of classification) and the structure.  I am of the opinion that fluid classification should be kept away from ones structure as the repercussions of classification changes are too great.

Just some thoughts :)